# Plotting twitter data with R

Tags: r, twitter, ggplot2

Using a tutorial that I found online, I'm trying to plot the tweets (retrieved by R) by location with `ggplot2` but when I try to run the code in the console, this error appears:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Here's the code:

```
library(twitteR)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(stringr)
library(igraph)
library(reshape2)
## Twitter authentication
consumer_key <- "XXX"
consumer_secret <- "XXX"
access_token <- "XXX"
access_secret <- "XXX"
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,
                    access_secret)

#Search Tweets
tweets2 = searchTwitter("Rio2016",lang="en",n=5000)
tweetsDF2 = twListToDF(tweets2)
tweetsDF2$longitude <- as.numeric(tweetsDF2$longitude)
tweetsDF2 <- tweetsDF2[!is.na(tweetsDF2$longitude),]


#Initialize map of Globe
tweetMap <- ggplot(map_data("world"))
#Create lines for countries, etc.
tweetMap <- tweetMap + geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), color = gray(2/3), lwd = 1/3)
#Add in our geo-tagged data
tweetMap <- tweetMap + geom_point(data=tweetsDF2,aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), color = "red", alpha = 1/2, size = 2)
tweetMap
```

It seems R doesn't recognize the Lat Lon data pulled out from twitter.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the imported `lat` and `long` columns are numeric?

Comment: Should be in this format  longitude     latitude
-43.38955547 -22.97333803

Comment: please provide `dput(head(tweetsDF2))` - format of the data is critical

Comment: longitude = c("-43.38955547", "0.47598159", 
    "-97.13954053", "-43.38853963", "-75.6163788", "-43.17986794"
    ), latitude = c("-22.97333803", "51.73184621", "49.89034914", 
    "-22.96872994", "40.5774002", "-22.91000096")),

Comment: Even though this is not a `dput` output, this looks like the longitude and latitude values are stored as a character vector instead of numeric vector. Try `tweetsDF2$longitude <- as.numeric(tweetsDF$longitude)` (and the same for the latitude column)

Comment: doesn't work: Error: object 'tweetsDF' not found

Comment: It's `tweetsDF2`. You forgot the `2`.

Comment: Ah ok I was wrong. However It doesn't work: Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Comment: can you edit your code reflecting how did you transform lat, long to numeric?

Comment: Ok, I've just edited the code

Comment: @AndreaAngeli you converted `longitude` to `numeric`, but you need to convert `latitude` to `numeric` as well.